# write in to file using fwrite() in table formate

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am having this code working well and ait fetch all my data to excel sheet...but it's not coming in correct format...what if i want to write data in to format of tabel look like
this.. as i mention below

```
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
    <tbody> 

         <tr>   <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data['0']; ?>" >
            <td><?php echo $data['2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['3']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['8']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['9']; ?></td>          
            <td><?php echo $data['11']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['12']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['4']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['5']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['6']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['13']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $data['10']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['14']; ?></td>
            <td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit">
            <input  name="BOOK" type="submit" value="Book" style="color:#d90f0f">

            </td>
            </tr>



    </tbody>
     </table>"






<?php 
            include 'functions.php';
          ob_start();




  if($_POST['types'] == 'name') {  

      $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE name='".$_POST['filter']."'                               ORDER BY id     DESC ";  
   }  
                     elseif($_POST['types'] == 'mobile') {  

        $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE mobile='".$_POST['filter']."' ORDER BY id   DESC ";  
   } 
          elseif($_POST['types'] == 'OccasionType') {  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE OccasionType='".$_POST['filter']."' ORDER BY id DESC ";  
        } 

     elseif($_POST['types'] == 'InquiryDate') {  
 $query="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE TodayDate between '".$_POST['From']."' and   '".$_POST['TO']."' ORDER BY id DESC " ;  
   }

  elseif($_REQUEST['types'] == 'OccasionDate') {  
                 $que="SELECT * FROM visitor_detail WHERE date between       '".$_REQUEST['From']."' and '".$_REQUEST['To']."' ORDER BY id DESC ";  
                }
    else {  
             $query = "SELECT * FROM visitor_detail ORDER BY id DESC ";  
        } 

   $sql = mysql_query($query); 


              $line1="Id\tgender\tname\tmobile\taddress\temail\totherno\tzipcode\tOccasionType\tdate\tgue      st\tdescription\tTodayDate\tauther\t";
         $data="$line1\n";
       $br = '<br>';

      $fileName = "./my.txt";
  $file = fopen($fileName, "w");
  fwrite($file, $data."\n");
         $i=1;  
             while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
                  {
        $line2=$i . "\t" . $row['gender'] . "\t" . $row['name'] . "\t" .                                                     $row['mobile'] . "\t" .    $row['address'] . "\t" . $row['email'] . "\t" . $row['otherno']  . "\t" .     $row['zipcode'] .    "\t" . $row['OccasionType'] . "\t" . $row['date'] . "\t"                                 . $row['guest'] . "\t" .    $row['description'] . "\t" . $row['TodayDate'] . "\t" .     $row['auther'] . "\t";
  $data1=$line2.$br;
     echo $data1;
          fwrite($file, $data1);
            $i++;
  }
            fclose($file);



 header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my.csv');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  fclose($file); ?>
```

Comment: Then you just have to change your PHP code to generate pseudo HTML code in your Excel file instead of using `\t` separator which represent a TSV file. (Excel can read HTML code like <table>)

Comment: but what if i want to download it in excel and PDF..in the table formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing inside text file

```
$fileName = "./my.txt";
```

and reading csv file

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my.csv');
```

I think it should be

```
$fileName = "./my.csv";
```

Comment: yes sorry i have did it by my self before... i just forget to update it...but what if i want to download it in excel and PDF..in the table formate